# How does a relying party learn a PageSigner server's public key?

Tags: private-key, oracles, public-key

Hoping for some insight Into to page signing... I understand that:

- https://tlsnotary.org/pagesigner.html can provide proofs that a specific web page was returned from a third-party TLS-protected server.
- it's possible to set up an AWS instance to "provably" run the PageSigner server.

What I can't understand is: if you give me a signed statement, and you tell me that it has been signed by a specific PageSigner server running in AWS (with untampered code), **how do I know which public key is  associated with this PageSigner server**? I can verify that the server you tell me about is running untampered code, but how do I interrogate this server to learn its public key (for verifying signatures)?

The PageSigner service [generates a keypair at boot time](https://github.com/tlsnotary/pagesigner-oracles/blob/7071cf8010d829ecd3ff0a55963cff698a2dd630/notary/rc.local#L31) (stored in a RAM-backed filesystem at `/dev/shm`) -- and it [outputs the public key to the AWS Console](https://github.com/tlsnotary/pagesigner-oracles/blob/7071cf8010d829ecd3ff0a55963cff698a2dd630/notary/rc.local#L36) for the service operator to see -- but I can't see where/how this key is **verifiably published** for the rest of the world to see.

I expect I'm missing something straightforward... but from the outside world, if I don't know which public key the PageSigner service is using, how can I tell that a proof was signed by this particular PageSigner instance?